# Which sqlite query should i use in this case

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select

I  have two tables(and their columns) in my DB:

```
CUSTOMERS(ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ADDRESS);
 ORDERS (ID, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_PRICE, DATE_ORDER DATE, ID_CUSTOMER, AMOUNT);
```

Here is what should I exactly do:

1. List the first and last names of the customers along with the count
   of their orders.
2. List the first and last names of the customers and calculate the total sum of their orders.

Please make series of SELECTs and sort each one by FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the `customers` table with an aggregate query on the `orders` table:

```
SELECT   firstname, lastname, num_orders, sum_orders
FROM     customers
JOIN     (SELECT   id_customer, COUNT(*) AS num_orders, SUM(amount) AS sum_orders
          FROM     orders
          GROUP BY id_customer) OR id_customer = id
ORDER BY 1, 2
```